# (clang) How to parse macros themselves, getting an ast where possible?

Tags: clang

Hi I'm using clang to extract information from c files.
And I'm trying to extract the values of macros.

e.g. from this I'd want the value '13' or an ast (+ (* 3 4) 1):

```
#define SOME_CONSTANT 3*4+1
```

or from a macro function, I'd want an ast e.g. (SOME_MACROFUNC (x y) (+ (add4 x) (* y 9))) :

```
int add4(int q) {return q+4;}
#define SOME_MACROFUNC(x,y) add4(x)+y*9
```

So far I've managed to iterate through all the macros via the 'Preprocessor' class's macro_begin() and macro_end() functions.

Then from that I've gotten the macro names, and from the 'MacroInfo' class I've been able to get whether the macro is functionlike (including param names) or not. I've also got access to the tokens in the macro, but I am only able to get the token kind e.g: string_literal, identifier, comma, l_paren, r_paren, etc.

So two things:

1. How do I access the actual value of the tokens, rather than just their kinds.
2. Is there a way to generate an ast from the macros given their tokens?
   One way I thought would be to parse my source code, then extract the macros, and using their names, add code including those macros to my source and reparse it to get the ast.

e.g. Something like:

```
char *tempSOME_CONSTANT = SOME_CONSTANT;    
void tempSOME_MACROFUNC(char *x, char *y) {SOME_MACROFUNC(x,y);}
```

Though this method seems really hacky, and probably would have trouble with macros that aren't statement or expression like.

Thanks.

edit:
 To clarify I mainly want the expanded body (until no macros are left, only non macro tokens) of each macro.

edit2 Solved some what:

If anyones interested I intend to expand the body of the macro manually.

"preprocessor.getSpelling(token)" to get the token value.

"preprocessor.getIdentifierTable().get(StringRef(spelling))" to get identinfo for the token.

And using "clang\lib\Lex\PPMacroExpansion.cpp" as a reference.

Still thinking about how to pass it to the parser without reparsing the whole source tree, but that shouldn't be too difficult to figure out.

Thanks to Ira Baxter for the discussion, it helped me iron out the problem.

Comment: To get an AST for a macro body, its content has to be well formed.  What do you do with "#define INTARRAYSTART  int["?

Comment: I would have to ignore such cases. So I'd need to be able to detect for that as well. If I could some how put the macros' tokens through the parser, clang could do that for me with the diagnostics class.

Comment: So, what's the root type of the tree for a macro body?  Here's a fun one: "#define trouble x*y;"

Comment: Well the since the tokens in this would be: x, multiply and y (I would be getting it from the "trouble's" "MacroInfo" class's token list), it would be the binary operator multiply.

Comment: It could also be a declaration.  Which it is depends on the context in which it is found.   Also consider what happens if it is in the following context:  ";s.trouble  (t);"; now both x and y belong "more strongly" to the elements of the context than to each other.  What if that context is buried inside a preprocessor conditional that can be true? cannot be true?

Comment: A variation: "#define trouble2 x+y" in context  "--trouble2*3"

Comment: In the case of macro using other macros, I was hoping to expand it until no macros remain. For cases like "s.trouble(t);", I could discard parsing them based on the usage of some symbols/keywords like ".", but I think I'm missing your point there (maybe a use different example?).

Comment: I see what you mean though about the "trouble x*y;", maybe if there was a way to avoid seeing the code as declarations and only as statements and expressions.

Comment: For the "trouble" macro, while it might parse as [times [x] [y]], in the context of "s.trouble(t)" the entire parse is [times [access [s] [x]] [funcall [y] [argument [t]]] which looks only faintly like the parsed macro.  The "trouble2" macro makes this even worse.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about "trouble2"?

Comment: Just substitute the macro body of trouble2 into the example context, and parse the result.  The point is that AST for the macro body may not resemble the AST of the substituted macro in context, so its hard to tell how valuable having the macro parsed as an AST is.

Comment: Narrowing down what I want, are the macros used to represent constants (e.g. like enum values) and functions (i.e. ones that return expressions based on the params, or ones that call another function or a series of functions). I think for at least those it should be possible to sanely generate an ast. Whilst throwing out any macros that contain anything like declarations or incomplete code.

Comment: Yes :-}  You can see "x+y" has little to do with that.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. But I think that is solved by just expanding the macros before trying to generate the ast. So that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Sure, but then you don't need an AST for the macro body itself.

Comment: I intend to use the ast from the macro body to convert it into another language, for this is for generating bindings to c libraries. Since some libraries like opengl and lua quite irritatingly use macros for enums and functions.

Comment: Are you willing to consider a non-Clang solution?

Comment: Probably not since my program is all but complete except for this part. Are you talking about your software?, I've heard a little about it.

Comment: OK, since you are Clang committed, and you know about my software, I'll leave it at that with one tidbit: DMS's C/C++ front ends represent macros explicity (apparantly as does Clang), has substring parsing ability, and can be coerced into parsing the macro bodies that way.  (My discussion about the issues above is partly derived from working with that).

Comment: Well, I'm dropping in 2 years later, but... i just wanted to point out that what has been made explicit in examples -- but which hasn't been made explicit in English -- is that function-like macros are inherently unsemantic. AST's *do not make sense* without semantics. As the language implementation is concerned, the content of your `3*4+1` macro is indeed the series of unicode symbols making up `3*4+1`, and no more. Only where the macro is invoked can this code gain its semantics and sensibly make its way onto an AST.

Answer (score 8):

I am working on something very similar. I use clang front end for collecting the context (w.r.t. class, function etc.) in which a macro is defined and then use a (pseudo) expression parser to figure out if the macro-body is a valid expression or not. The ultimate goal is to transform the macro into C++ declaration. Recently we got a paper accepted into [ICSM](http://selab.fbk.eu/icsm2012/)-2012 that explains how we achieve this.

The tools -the demacrofier- used to get rid of macros is hosted [here](https://github.com/hiraditya/cpp2cxx)

Ira Baxter's examples are very insightful in the way macros are used. However, the %age of those macros are very less \ref(An Empirical analysis of C Preprocessor use by Ernst et al.). Currently, I am focusing more on common cases.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. If you're interested, my current solution which is a bit wonky in that it occasionally crashes my program  (I think I fixed it by fiddling with the error output settings, it's been a little bit since I've worked on it), is to make a function with the macro in the body, if it has params, I give the function the same params each with the type "void*". Which I then send to the parser, and if it works, I use it.

Comment: You can even give type of T(templated) to each parameter. That will only break those macros which reference variables defined at the use site.

Answer (score 0):

One hack that may or may not be useful is to temporarily redefine all function-like macros as functions. In your case:

`#define SOME_MACROFUNC(x,y) add4(x)+y*9`

will become

`extern int SOME_MACROFUNC(int x, int y);`

Then you can run this through a regular AST Matcher or visitor and do whatever processing you need (including refactoring, if appropriate). This doesn't scale well, but if the number of macros is well-known and limited, it could be an acceptable solution.

To make this cleaner, you can create a separate header file that is only used by clang and make sure clang finds it first when running your analysis, this way you don't need to modify your original source base.